# Writing back to original places after retrieval from Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I can successfully retrieve documents from firestore, the trouble is, i do not know how to put them back where they came from!!
My app is a court booking system, it uses 7 fragments that represent the days of the week. Each fragment contains buttons that represent booking slots throughout the day. When a button is pressed, the court booking activity fires showing textviews and spinners.
The information I save to firestore includes a unique number representing a datestamp and a booking id that represents the id of the button that was pressed.... from here, I am lost, i need to write the retrieved database info back to their relevant places but i dont have anything unique in the way of widgets. The buttons are unique but all they do is fire a non unique court booking activity... any help appreciated... sorry for length, quite possibly more to add when answering questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to a document in Firestore you need to know the complete path to that document. You'll need to track the necessary IDs in your code, in a way that you can synchronize it with your UI elements.

A simple first pass could be to add a non-editable view (e.g. a label) to your UI for each document, and set the document ID (or entire path) in there. Then when the user clicks a button, you find the corresponding view with the ID, and from that can recreate the `DocumentReference` that you need to update.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for that, your reply got me thinking along a different path. I already had the unique ID for the document but i got stuck down the wrong path as to how i would need to display it.. back to the drawing board...many thanks :)